# short form calling method without parentheses?

Tags: javascript

for example, I write this code:

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4,5]

const res = a.slice.call(a)
console.log(res)
```

why slice without parentheses? because it's return value, yes? or I'm wrong?

Why I'm not can then write such code:

```
const a = [1,2,3,4,5]
const res = a.slice(0, a.length).call(a)
console.log(res)
```

what is the problem?

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice` is a function and function is an object and that object has `call` method, which calls the `slice`. [Check more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call),

> The call() method calls a function with a given this value and
>   arguments provided individually.

`a.slice` is a function and function has the call `method` which calls the `slice` function.

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4,5]
const b = [1,2];
const res = a.slice.call(b) // calls the function with context of b
console.log(res); // [1,2]
```

On the other hand `a.slice(0, a.length)` returns an array and array does not have `call` function, which will result into an error.

Answer (score 3):

`a.slice` is a function that refers to `Array.prototype.slice`. Functions have functions on their prototype as well, including `call` - just like you can do `a.slice()` where `a` refers to an array, you can do `fn.call()` where `fn` refers to a function.

But in your second example, you're trying to use `call` on an *array*, not a function: `a.slice(0, a.length)` resolves to an *array*, and the `Array` prototype has no `call` method. You can only use `call` on objects (including functions) which have a `call` property, or which have a `call` property on one of their prototype objects.

Answer (score 2):

`a.slice.call(a)` is calling the `slice` method with `a` as the context. [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

> The call() method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually.

Incidentally, this is the same thing as doing:

`a.slice()`.

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4,5]

console.log(a.slice.call(a));
console.log(a.slice());
```

See the snippet. Both results are the same.

The latter example does:

```
a.slice(0, a.length).call(a)
```

Which is calling `call` on the result of `slice`, which is an array. `call` is a method on `Function` not `Array` so this doesn't work.